# 第3月曜日 3rd Monday or Monday in the third week

Tags: meaning, context

第3月曜日 I'm not sure the actual meaning.

1. 3rd Monday that some month may not have this day ( Monday that the date is the third ) for clearer explainantion in picture below

[image]

2. Monday that is in the third week ( 1 month has 4 weeks and this 第３月曜日 is Monday that's in 3rd week )

Comment: In your understanding of #2, what date do you think that is?

Comment: I'll use the picture I posted as an example. Monday in 1st week is 3, and Monday in 3rd week is 17.

Comment: Okay, just making sure. Usually I would say "the third Monday".

Comment: No... "the third Monday" is the 17th. The third Monday that happens in the month. If you wanted to talk about that other day, you'd say "Monday the third." But it sounds like the English is confusing you...

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for that too. The answer is #2 .

Comment: My bad, I didn't make that clear. I mean in May only. Monday the 27th is in the April.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

第3月曜日 refers to the Monday that comes for the third time in the given month. All months have 第3月曜日 because all months have at least 21 days. Likewise, there is no month that has 第6月曜日. Note that 第3 in Japanese never refers to the third day of a month in the first place.

Also note that your definition #2, "Monday that is in the third week", is probably inaccurate. For example, The 第3月曜日 of September 2020 is the 21th (see the calendar below), but I think many people think "Monday that is in the third week" refers to the 14th.

[image]